# Multiple cloud run services with a large shared codebase

Tags: docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-run

New to server-side development and quite lost here - I am building a mobile app which (currently) uses Google Cloud Run for its backend services, implemented in Python. I have a single container which takes in different post requests to perform relevant operations - on Cloud Storage/Firestore - called directly from the app or from  Cloud Functions triggered.

The issue is that as I add more and more endpoints, it is getting unwieldily to have a single service for the entire app. Specifically, some functions have machine learning dependencies (eg. pytorch/transformers) which makes the container image pretty large.

Ideally, I would like separate containers utilizing some/all of the shared codebase but only pulling in the required dependencies in each case. Eg. Separating lighter
Firestore triggered functions from the heavier machine learning stuff. What would a recommended 'clean' way to organize this?

Comment: You will need to separate your application into separate containerized applications. Keep the code separately for each container. Pulling in shared libraries or blocks of code is fine but do not try to mix everything together.

Comment: Thank you - I guess that's the way to go.